# What's the best way to write an if statement that makes a string equal to something else

Tags: c#, string

I'm working on a project and need to set old data starting with a 0, 1, or 2 to simply equal a level.

```
if (dr["Acct"].ToString().Substring(0,1) == "0"
    || dr["Acct"].ToString().Substring(0,1) == "1"
    || dr["Acct"].ToString().Substring(0,1) == "2")
{
    // then Level = Balance Sheet
}
```

I am essentially trying to say if the substring is 0, 1, or 2, then it should equal the level called Balance Sheet.

Comment: And what is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: And the problem you have is?

Comment: Title asks what is the best way to express this intention, and I think you'll both agree that this isn't it.

Comment: @Rotem, sure, but also, 'best' is very subjective.

Comment: @Rotem - I'd think many would agree that it's not worth optimizing a one-off task

Comment: @Sach It's very minorly subjective. Offer your opinion as an answer and if many people agree with it, they will upvote it.

Comment: I'd suggest that if you cannot recognise that you can extract `dr[“Acct”].ToString().Substring(0,1)` into a local variable, you're not the right demographic to use this site.

Comment: @Rotem - I try to welcome those who are expending effort. But this site isn't *for* beginners. It's for "professional and enthusiast programmers"

Comment: @Rotem - no, if they ask "how can I improve my code even though it works?", the correct answer is to send them to other sites on the stack exchange network, such as Code Review. I.e. sites where they review code.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Fair point, but my original argument still stands. You didn't vote this as off topic with a recommendation to post on Code Review instead, did you?

Comment: @Rotem  -no, I can't do that through existing UI and I am *incredibly* lazy.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever if you do suggest users post on other sites like code review, please also suggest they read the on-topic page of the Help section first; in its current form, this post would likely be closed as _off-topic_ on CR because there is little information about how the code is used.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It seems not lazy enough to avoid this argument :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have want to check multiple strings i would store in string array and check it for better readability

```
public string[] dataStartsWith= {"0","1","2"};

if(dataStartsWith.Contains(dr["Acct"].ToString().Substring(0,1))){
    Level = "Balance Sheet"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

String operations are expensive, and this is probably a more readable way to go about it.

```
string acctVal = dr["Acct"]?.ToString();
char[] balanceSheetVals= {'0', '1', '2'};

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(acctVal))
{
   if(balanceSheetVals.contains(acctVal[0]))
   {
      Level = "Balance Sheet";
   }
   else
   {
      //defaults
   }
}
else
{
   //defaults
}
```

Edit: Most props to @Rotem who cleaned this up a lot

Comment: I would check for `String.IsNullOrEmpty` before using `Substring` unless you're positive that can't be.
And also the expensive part here is more likely to be `dr["aact"]` (whatever that may be) rather than the substring operation, but the comment on readability still stands.

Comment: Good point on the null checks, added with spots for default handling.

I agree the initial lookup in the dr would be the most expensive assuming it's a real world size of a collection, but trying to share that keeping string operations to a minimum is a good practice.

Comment: @Rotem Another good point, saves the extra string allocation.

Comment: Your `balanceSheetVals` would need to be of type `char` though, as indexing into a string returns a `char` and not a single character substring

Comment: And you nailed it again, you rock @Rotem

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if some `string` starts with some other `string`, I personally find [`String.StartsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith) to be more readable and more clearly state the intent of the code than using `String.Substring`.

```csharp
var target = dr["Acct"].ToString();
if (target.StartsWith("0")
   || target.StartsWith("1")
   || target.StartsWith("2")
)
{
   Level = "Balance Sheet";
}
```

Comment: I must have a case of the Mondays, how would it fail anymore than using `Substring(0, 1)`?

Comment: Sorry, the Mondays are all mine. Deleted.